# Start/Stop -AzVM Not Working Properly with Automation

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

I have a group of VMs under a Resource Group. I have created an automation runbook to schedule switching on and off the VMs. The runbook type is PowerShell Workflow and runtime version is 5.1. The runbook code is:

```
workflow VM-On-Off-ScheduleCode
{
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $TagName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $TagValue,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Boolean]
    $PowerStat
    )

# Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process

# Connect to Azure with system-assigned managed identity
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context

# Set and store context
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext 

$vms = Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines -TagName $TagName -TagValue $TagValue

Foreach -Parallel ($vm in $vms){
        if($PowerStat){
            Start-AzVM -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName;
            Write-Output "Starting $($vm.Name)";
        }
        else{
            Stop-AzVM -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Force;
            Write-Output "Stopping $($vm.Name)";
        }
    }
}
```

The 3 parameters it requires are Tag Name, Tag Value, and a Boolean where True means VMs to be switch on and False means to be switched off. I have checked multiple times that the Tag Name and Value are properly configured in all the VMs.

The issue I am facing is that whenever it runs via a schedule, most of the times one or two VMs are not switched on/off. There is no pattern in this exception as one day there could be 1 VM, another day it could be 3 VMs, and also the VMs may not be same always. I have checked for Error and found none. I have run the code in the testing pane and found it to be working perfectly. I will be greatful if anyone can resolve my issue.

My expectation is all the said VMs should switch on or off without any exception

Comment: I would check the Event Viewer on the Azure Server to see if there are any errors.  What does ON/OFF actually do?

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with the system identity. When executed on a schedule, the runbook may not be able to connect to Azure using the system-assigned managed identity. You can try using a `user-assigned` managed identity instead of a system-assigned managed identity to resolve the issue.

*Created a user managed identity and connected as shown:*

```bash
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId "UserclientID").context
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
```

```
workflow new
{
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[String]
$TagName,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[String]
$TagValue,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[Boolean]
$PowerState
)

$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId "Userclient_ID").context
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
$vms = Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines -TagName $TagName -TagValue $TagValue
Foreach -Parallel ($vm  in  $vms){
if($PowerState){
Start-AzVM -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName;
Write-Output "Starting $($vm.Name)";
}
else{
Stop-AzVM -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Force;
Write-Output "Stopping $($vm.Name)";
    }
 }
}
```

As showed in the image, obtain the `user client ID` from the set-up `user managed identity`.

[image]

***Output:***

I tested the two scenarios in which the powerstate is running and vice versa. It worked as expected.

[image]

[image]

*Below are the few concerns for these kind of issues:*

- Include a `timeout`  for the VM. Because it is possible that the VMs are timing out if they take longer than intended to start or stop. So, by adding timeout with the `start-AZVM`, you can increase the VM's timeout value.
- Once the job running is completed, check the job logs under `Process Automation >> Jobs` in the `automation account`. It can sometimes help to identify the cause.

If still the issue persists, you can schedule start/stop VM's by triggering with Azure functions as clearly given in this [article](https://charbelnemnom.com/schedule-azure-vm-using-azure-function/) by @Charbel Nemnom.

Comment: Just want to clarify that this issue has no pattern. Even there are days when all the VMs are switched on or off as expected. Again there could be days when only VM1 is not switched on and on another day it could be VM3 and VM7. There is also no relationship between exceptions for switch on or off. There are days when say VM3 was not switched on via automation and has to be done manually in the morning but at night it got switched off via automation.